# PHP array_push one array into another

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to add one array inside of another using array_push or something similar.

What I would like to achieve will look like this:

```
$years = array(
    "2017" => array("Value01", "Value02"),
    "2016" => array("Value03")
);
```

What would be the best way to create an array within another? I have tried the following:

```
array_push($years, "2016" => array());
```

This just gives a

> 500 error.

And:

```
array_push($years, "2016");
```

This does add a new array within $yearshowever it is called "2018" and the "2016" value is place inside that 2018 array. I have manually created the 2017 array already, so I assume it is just incrementing on that number for some reason.

Comment: You can set the nested array by key: `$years[2016] = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'];`

Comment: no need to use `array_push` for this, simply write `$years["2016"] = $array;`

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The answer to your question is in the section ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to do with `array_push()`:-

```
array_push($years, array("2016" => array()));
```

But what you want, for that do:-

```
$years["2016"]= array();
```

Output:- https://eval.in/834452

Answer (score 0):

Without push :

```
<?php 

$years = [];

$years[][] = 'value1';
$years[][] = 'value2';

var_dump($years);
?>
```

Or:

```
$years['someKey'] = [value1, value2 ....]
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you dont need to use array_push 
there are many ways of doing it, for instance :

```
$years["whatever the key"]= array("whatever the value");
```

the result will be like :

```
$years = array(
"2017" => array("Value01", "Value02"),
"whatever the key" => array("whatever the value") );
```

Comment: Php documentation says:   "Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array, it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function."