# Push key and value pair into multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please note that this is not a duplicate - but an extension of these questions below)

[PHP array_push one array into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187462/php-array-push-one-array-into-another)

[array_push into a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870847/array-push-into-a-multi-dimensional-array)

I am trying to array_push into a multidimensional array but want to keep the array key of the second array.

Example:

```
<?php
$samplearray = array(
array('name' => "Joe Bloggs", 'age' => "30", 'sex' => "Male", 'title' => "Mr" ),
array('name' => "Jane Bloggs", 'age' => "30", 'sex' => "Female", 'title' => "Mrs" ),
array('name' => "Little Bloggs", 'age' => "10", 'sex' => "Male", 'title' => "Master" ),    
);

array_push ($samplearray[0],"Inserted Value");

print_r($samplearray);
?>
```

The output for this is:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Joe Bloggs"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["title"]=>
    string(2) "Mr"
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Inserted Value" <-- INSERTED VALUE
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Jane Bloggs"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(6) "Female"
    ["title"]=>
    string(3) "Mrs"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Little Bloggs"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["title"]=>
    string(6) "Master"
  }
}
```

I want to insert a key along with the value but when I try that - it fails. Can you please advice

```
array_push ($samplearray[0]['insertedvalue'],"Inserted Value");
```

returns a NULL value for the inserted key on local server but fails on PHPfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
        $samplearray = array(
        array('name' => "Joe Bloggs", 'age' => "30", 'sex' => "Male", 'title' => "Mr" ),
        array('name' => "Jane Bloggs", 'age' => "30", 'sex' => "Female", 'title' => "Mrs" ),
        array('name' => "Little Bloggs", 'age' => "10", 'sex' => "Male", 'title' => "Master" ),
    );

    $samplearray[0]['othername'] = 'lalala';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($samplearray);
```

and this should print:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Joe Bloggs
        [age] => 30
        [sex] => Male
        [title] => Mr
        [othername] => lalala
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jane Bloggs
        [age] => 30
        [sex] => Female
        [title] => Mrs
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Little Bloggs
        [age] => 10
        [sex] => Male
        [title] => Master
    )
```

)

Answer (score 2):

This must be what you need.

```
$samplearray[0]['insertedvalue'] = "Inserted Value";
```